# How to show the content of a list in a second table once the first table has no more space

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I want to pull data from DB and list it in a table.
The screen size is fixed and they shall not be extended(no scrolling).
Once there is no more "space" for table1, I want that the following items to be listed on a sided table2. So I don't want that the screen gets extended, scrolled.

This is how my code is.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">TIME</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">LOCATION</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">MESSAGE</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">TIME</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">LOCATION</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">MESSAGE</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This picture shows how I want my implementation:

[image: side by side tables]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the JSTL core begin and end attributes:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">TIME</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">LOCATION</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">MESSAGE</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${somedata}" var="data" begin = "0" end = "5">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${data.time}</td>
                                <td>${data.message}</td>
                                <td>${data.location}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">TIME</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">LOCATION</th>
                            <th style="background-color: transparent">MESSAGE</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${somedata}" var="data" begin = "6" end = "11">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${data.time}</td>
                                <td>${data.location}</td>
                                <td>${data.message}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like you to try this "column-count"-techique:

```
div {
  column-count: 4;
  column-width: 150px;
  column-rule: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/qqgBMN